# I can't use the jQuery toggle on a svg

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the colours of my svg by clicking on it. I managed to create my click function with jquery only I would like to use toggle. I have tried several times ... nothing works I do not understand why, do you have an idea? I leave below a link to a codepen

https://codepen.io/christophedelamare/pen/KKqGrYJ

```
$(".one").click(function(){$(this).css("color", "blue");
```

});

help me please :,)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you need to toggle the values. Instead, every time you click, it just keeps setting the same color.

Here's a suggestion:

You can use JQuery's `toggleClass` for this.

You'll need to add a new CSS selector with  the new color for each class

```
.one {
color: black;
cursor: pointer;
}
.one.clicked {
  color: blue;
}
.two {
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}
.two.clicked {
  color: yellow;
}
.three {
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}
.three.clicked {
  color: red;
}
.four {
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}
.four.clicked {
  color: green;
}
```

And then combine all your JS events into a single one

```
$(".one, .two, .three, .four").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

I myself usually prefer to do these changes with a class instead of adding inline CSS, even if it's a little bit of more work sometimes.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It is much clearer and more logical. Also I didn't understand why it wasn't working on my site but I was using a bad version of Jquery

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js 

A real beginner's mistake. Thanks again for this